# I need to put my most recent 10 commits on a separate branch. Then I want to work off the commit directly before these 10 on master

Tags: git, github

I need to put my most recent 10 commits on a separate branch. Then I want to work off the commit directly before these 10 on master and make my new work live, without the most recent 10 commits being part of the push into production. The most recent 10 commits have been put on hold indefinitely and should have been put on a separate branch in the first place only to be merged once completed. If I push them into production now the site breaks since they are unfinished.

How would I go about shifting these most recent commits onto a separate branch and working right from my old commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a new branch
2. Switch back to master
3. Run `git reset --hard <last desired commit>` to reset history to that point.

Note that this is not compatible with sharing; you will need to `git push -f`, and anyone else who pulls will get messed up.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by anyone who pulls will get messed up? Is that only if they already have the project? What if it is their first time pulling?

Comment: I mean if they had the old history, and then they pull after you rewrite history.

Comment: You can't pull if you don't already have a local clone, after all

Comment: Yes, of course. I was thinking during the cloning process. Thank you for the help.